# How to create and write a file into a folder on the same directory?

Tags: c++

I've been creating and writing into a file in the directory I have all my project files, but now that i finished everything, I'm trying to tidy things up.

My executable is creating and writing into a file in the same directory that it's placed on. Now, I've created a folder in this same directory called 'models' and i need the previous mentioned file to be created in this folder. I have a Windows machine and i'm using C++.

What i have at the moment, in a simplified way is:

```
void createFile(string fich){
    ofstream file(fich);
}
```

I've tried things like

```
void createFile(string fich){
    string path = "../models/" + fich;
    ofstream file(path);
}
```

without any success. How could i solve this?

Comment: The two dots mean "move up one level in the directory tree". Just `"models/" + fich"` should give you the sub-folder of the current directory.

Comment: I figured that the two dots were for that, but that for some reason it would work too... I actually tried with "/models/" + fich to see if it would work, but i guess i the first '/' wasn't supposed to be there. Thanks!

Comment: A path starting with `/` indicates starting at the root directory, meaning an absolute path.